# When to use "gets" with "I"?

Tags: american-english, learning

I've been listening to the song ["Crack A Bottle"](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/eminem/crackabottle.html). In "50 Cents" first verse he says,

> "I **gets** what the !@#$ I want so what I trick"

As far as know, *s* is atached to the words like, get(s), work(s), like(s), move(s) etc, when the subject is third person, like, he, she, it, etc.

So, the question is why have 50 used *gets* instead of *get*?

Comment: This is a dialect use; most hip-hop music, even that composed and performed by white artists, employs African-American dialect.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, it's incorrect grammar.

Generally speaking, don't expect popular songs to employ good grammar; they usually use whatever style of speaking appeals to their target audience.

As @StoneyB mentioned, this is a common part of the African-American dialect.  There isn't any standardization about when the dialect puts "s" on the end of singular verbs and when they don't.